# Java3D Maven Repository for 1.5.2

Tags: maven, repository, java-3d

I'm at my wit's end trying to get Java3D working with Maven. The latest version in the [Maven core repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/java3d) is 1.3.1, but [there don't seem to be any 64-bit dll files (without installers)](https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds-old.html) that will work with such an early version! It seems that the 1.5.2 dll I donwloaded is incompatible (unsurprisingly).

Does anyone know of a repository that has at least version 1.4.0?

Otherwise, looks like I'm going to have to learn JOGL instead and change all my code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather make a request for enhancement. Maybe we could publish Maven on Maven Central or at least in our development repository. Please check whether you're using Java 3D 1.6, look at [that](http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb) if you don't know how to install it.